# Cannot delete or update parent row Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a design and scenario entity.
I'm getting an error when removing a Design that contains one or more scenarios.

The design entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Design {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] image;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "design", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Scenario> ScenarioSet;
```

The scenario entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Scenario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "design_ID")
    private Design design;
```

As you can see A design can have more than one scenarios.
And Design is responsible for the relation.

My code to save a scenario:

```
    Design design = this.designService.getDesignById(designID);
    scenario.setDesign(design);
    this.scenarioService.saveScenario(scenario);
```

Saving it isn't a problem. I'm saving it this way because the scenario doesn't have an ID at first.

The error i'm getting:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`scenario`, CONSTRAINT `FKqmttw6jic4aplswy08wtkj5r7` FOREIGN KEY (`design_id`) REFERENCES `design` (`id`))   0.016 sec
```

This lets me think that It isn't cascading when I remove the Design.

Comment: Please, add the code which removes `Design`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `orphanRemoval=true` to your scenario list mapping in the `Design` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "design", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Scenario> ScenarioSet;
```

`CascadeType.ALL` (or precisely `CascadeType.REMOVE`) serve for cascading remove operation when you take an item from the collection and save the owning entity (`Design` in this case). To tell Hibernate to remove items in the collection when the owning entity (`Design`) is removed, you need to use the `orphanRemoval`attribute:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/